# Edit birth date

Tags: webform-civicrm, dashboard, dates

I have setup a webform to register people to an event, which we need to collect DOB. I have included the Birth Date field in the CiviCRM webform.

One person can register multiple people. If they do not know the DOB for other people I have told them that can be updated later by an admin user. I cannot see where can this be changed is the Civi admin area. Apologies if I am missing the obvious. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have a default layout, then there is a Date of Birth field on a contact's summary tab.

[image: contact summary]

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I had to turn on Demographics in the Other Panes here: /civicrm/admin/setting/preferences/display?reset=1. Helps to know what to look for. Cheers.